# SQL Server: Insert default values in table for missing months

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, algorithm

I have a table that has some products data that has a column structure like this:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | PRODUCT | COL4 | COL5 | FM_START | FM_END | FM | FM_NAME | FY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

I have another table that the fiscal month and fiscal year data (the last 5 columns), each month has a start date, end date, number and name.
Some products have missing months, that usually means no operations on these products at those specific months, but the missing rows are messing the data analysis we do with the tables afterwards.
What I'm looking for is an algorithm to identify the missing months for each product, grab the data for these months from Fiscal Calendar table, and insert them as rows into this table with some default values for the other columns.

Hoping that my explanation is quite clear, any one has some ideas how to achieve that?

EDIT: For each fiscal year, fiscal months can have slightly different start and end dates. Just thought to add if this piece of information is important.

Comment: Use a calendar table and `LEFT JOIN` from it.

Comment: Venn diagrams are quite self-explanatory https://i.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/001/480/370/d24.jpg

Comment: Post some sample rows from the data.

Comment: A calendar will generally have 1 row for every date, so you can choose a different fiscal period for each date. I fear your source table does not actually have a date column that you can use to "find" the associated fiscal period information - but that is based on your column names which provide no clues as to what they actually mean or contain.

Comment: @SMor FM_Start and FM_End are both date columns with the start and end date for each fiscal month, the first columns contain values associated with the product itself, not date information.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is ever to create a calendar set of tables among them one will be the month one like :

```
CREATE TABLE T_MONTH_MTH
(MTH_ID          INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
 MTH_MONTH_NUM   TINYINT NOT NULL CHECK (MTH_MONTH_NUM BETWEEN 1 AND 12),
 MTH_YEAR        SMALLINT NOT NULL CHECK (MTH_YEAR BETWEEN 1 AND 9999),
 MTH_BEGIN_DATE  DATE NOT NULL, 
 MTH_END_DATE    DATE NOT NULL, 
 CHECK (YEAR(MTH_BEGIN_DATE) = MTH_YEAR AND 
        MONTH(MTH_BEGIN_DATE) = MTH_MONTH_NUM ),
 CHECK (YEAR(MTH_END_DATE) = MTH_YEAR AND 
        MONTH(MTH_END_DATE) = MTH_MONTH_NUM ))
GO
```

Then populate it:

```
INSERT INTO T_MONTH_MTH VALUES (...);
```

Afterwhat you can add a RIGHT OUTER JOIN with this table to find gaps !

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Would that method work if each month has different starting and end dates for each fiscal year? I probably should have included that in the question, I'll edit it to add that piece.